# py2exe can't find module if in different path

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe

I'm trying to create an exe using the following config options -

```
setup(name='tidalZabbix',
      version=version,
      description='python module to submit job stats to Zabbix',
      url='',
      author='Me',
      author_email='me@company.com',
      license='',
      # folders with functions
      console=[{'script': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'code/tidal_zabbix.py')}],
      options={
          'build': {'build_base': 'c:/tidalZabbix/build'},
          'py2exe':
              {
                  'dist_dir': 'c:/tidalZabbix',
                  'includes': ['decimal'],
              }
      }
      )
```

I have a separate module in the code directory called `code/ZabbixSender.py`

when I try to run python setup.py py2exe I get the following error -

```
The following modules appear to be missing
['ZabbixSender']
```

If I move the `ZabbixSender.py` to the same location as my `setup.py` the build works fine.

ie. if I do this:

```
'includes': ['decimal', 'code.ZabbixSender'],
```

or

```
'includes': ['decimal', 'ZabbixSender'],
```

It still doesn't find the Module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to think this is bad error reporting by p2exe.

The solution has nothing to do with my py2exe config but in the tidal_zabbix.py script being called.

This was the "incorrect" import

`from ZabbixSender import ZabbixPacket, ZabbixSender`

As soon as I modified it to this -

`from code.ZabbixSender import ZabbixPacket, ZabbixSender`

The build worked with no issues.  Odd though considering running directly from python had no issues with the code.